# sed: how to replace \0, but not \\0

Tags: regex, sed, backslash

I'm doing a migration from mysql to postgres. As part of that I'm processing the mysql dump using sed before loading that into postgres.

My MySQL dump has some `\0` characters and postgres doesn't like them. So I'm replacing them using a space.

```
sed 's/\\0/ /g' $dumpfile
```

Noticed an issue when the line has `320.48k\\02. Easy Listening`.

```
$ echo '320.48k\\02. Easy Listening' | sed 's/\\0/ /g'
320.48k\ 2. Easy Listening
```

Thats not what I quite wanted. `\\` characters are followed by `0` is not a null character. and I want to keep as it is.

Any sed experts around to help?

Comment: As a workaround, you can replace all `\\0` with some strange code, then replace `\0` and finally write back your `\\0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can make the regex only match `\0` when it follows something other than `\`

```
$ echo '320.48k\\02. Easy Listening' | sed 's/\([^\\]\)\\0/\1 /g'
320.48k\\02. Easy Listening
```

That fixes the problem, but it fails when `\0` is at the start of the line, so make the preceding match optional:

```
$ echo '\0320.48k\\02. Easy\0Listening' | sed 's/\([^\\]\)\?\\0/\1 /g'
 320.48k\ 2. Easy Listening
```

This doesn't work though, because `\\0` can match the regex with zero occurences of the parenthesised sub-group.

Another alternative is to say the `\0` must either come at the start of the line, or the preceding character must not be `\`

```
$ echo '\0320.48k\\02. Easy\0Listening' | sed 's/\([^\\]\|^\)\\0/\1 /g'
 320.48k\\02. Easy Listening
```

(As a comment points out, this still gives the wrong result for odd numbers of backslashes.)

Comment: Not so fast! `echo hello\\\0world`

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem, but there is subtle bug. What if the input is `320.48k\\02. Easy\0Listening\\\0foo`?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to replace null characters (\0), you can use:

```
sed 's/\x0/ /g'
```

or

```
tr '\0' ' '
```

I use a lot

```
tr '\0' '\n'< /proc/13217/environ
```

to display environment of a process

Comment: The mysql dump already escapes null as `\0`. So only have `\0` in my data, not `\x0` character.

Comment: Why doesn't `sed` interpret `\0` as a NULL character like `tr` does?

Comment: I found it when I was looking how to replace `\0` on Linux console - and funny is that I needed this answer to use `sed` to replace `\0` with `\n` to display `/proc/.../environ` :)

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that `\\\0` would have to be replaced by `\\␣` and so on. So replace any sequence containing an odd number of backslashes followed by a `0` by those same backslashes except the last one followed by a space. The sequence needs to be preceded by a non-backslash character or the beginning of the line, otherwise `\\0` will match starting at the second backslash. If there are multiple consecutive `\0` sequences, they won't be caught because the first matched character is the character before the first backslash; you'll need to match them all and replace them by a single space.

```
sed -e 's/\(\([^\]\|^\)\(\\\\\)*\)\\0\(\(\\\\\)*\\0\)*/\1 /g'
```

If your sed doesn't have `\|`, use two separate substitution commands.

```
sed -e 's/^\(\(\\\\\)*\)\\0\(\(\\\\\)*\\0\)*/\1 /' -e 's/\([^\]\(\\\\\)*\)\\0\(\(\\\\\)*\\0\)*/\1 /g'
```

Alternatively, use Perl. Its [look-behind assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%3c!pattern%29) comes in handy to say “this must not follow a backslash”.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\\0/$1 /g'
```

In Perl, another approach is perhaps clearer: replace every backslash+character sequence, and compute the replacement text based on the following character.

```
perl -pe 's/\\(.)/$1 eq "0" ? " " : "\\$1"/eg'
```